# react-bootstrap modal unmounting with animation

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using react-bootstrap (0.28.3) with React embedded in a Backbone app.

In my Backbone view render I'm doing something like this:
`ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(MyModal, this.options}), this.el);`

When destroying the Backbone view / Backbone router changes route, I have an onDestroyed() which unmounts the React component.

```
    onDestroyed() {
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(this.el)
    }
```

However this causes the modal to disappear without the animation.

How can I unmount the react-bootstrap modal and gracefully wait for the animation?

Answer (score 4):

`Modal` takes a `show` prop, which will make modal fade if it's set to `false`. So if you can re-render the `MyModal` component with `show` set to `false` and put unmount logic in a `setTimeout` with required time, it should work.

Comment: Ideally I would like to have a callback or get some Promise for when the show=false is done, but it seems like this hook doesn't exist now.

Comment: There's an onExited callback in Modal, which is fired after transition is done. I hope this helps.

Comment: How do routers like react-router unmount react-bootstrap modals/overlays while keeping the animation? Is the onExited a common pattern?

Comment: Although I'm not really sure, it's probably using ReactCSSTransitionGroup under the hood.